# AngularJS calculate two dynamic values from an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am new to web development and I ran into a problem with arrays in AngularJS.

I have a `ng-repeat` sequence. In this sequence are two sliders, that are repeated over and over due to `ng-repeat`.

The corresponding HTML Snippet looks like this:

```
<h1>INDEX = {{index}}</h1>
  <div ng-repeat="alert in alerts">
      <rzslider rz-slider-model="alert.value"
              rz-slider-options="alert.options"></rzslider>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>
      <h4>{{alert.weighttitle}}</h4>
      <div>
        <md-slider flex md-discrete ng-model="alert.weight" step="1" min="1" max="100" aria-label="rating"></md-slider>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Considering that all that all the links and scripts are included and the controller is correctly set up.

The code above does the following:

- It displays a $scope.index from the angularJS controller.
- Two different sliders appear that iterate through an array called alerts. From there it takes some values.

The interesting snippet of the Controller looks like this:

```
$scope.alerts = [
  { id: 1,
    title: 'title1',
    weighttitle: 'weighttitle1',
    value: 1,
    weight: 10,
    options: {
      showTicks: true,
      hidePointerLabels: true,
      hideLimitLabels: true,
      stepsArray: [
        { value: 1, legend: '<10' },
        { value: 2, legend: '<50' },
        { value: 3, legend: '<250' },
        { value: 4, legend: '<500' },
        { value: 5, legend: '>500' }

      ]
    }
  },
  { id: 2,
    title: 'title2',
    weighttitle: 'weighttitle2',
    value: 5,
    weight: 1,
    options: {
      showTicks: true,
      hidePointerLabels: true,
      hideLimitLabels: true,
      stepsArray: [
        { value: 1, legend: '<2Mio' },
        { value: 2, legend: '<10Mio' },
        { value: 3, legend: '<50Mio' },
        { value: 4, legend: '<100Mio' },
        { value: 5, legend: '>100Mio' }

      ]
    }
  },
  { id: 3,
    title: 'title3',
    weighttitle: 'weighttitle3',
    value: 1,
    weight: 1,
    options: {
      showTicks: true,
      hidePointerLabels: true,
      hideLimitLabels: true,
      stepsArray: [
        { value: 1, legend: '<5%' },
        { value: 2, legend: '<10%' },
        { value: 3, legend: '<15%' },
        { value: 4, legend: '<20%' },
        { value: 5, legend: '>20%' }

      ]
    }
  },
  { id: 4,
    title: 'title4',
    weighttitle: 'weighttitle4',
    value: 3,
    weight: 69,
    options: {
      showTicks: true,
      hidePointerLabels: true,
      hideLimitLabels: true,
      stepsArray: [
        { value: 1, legend: '<5' },
        { value: 2, legend: '<10' },
        { value: 3, legend: '<15' },
        { value: 4, legend: '<20' },
        { value: 5, legend: '>20' }

      ]
    }
  },
];
```

The above snippet is part of a controller which is included in the HTML correctly and is therefore working.

My question is now how can I set up an `$scope.index` so that it is getting each `value` and each `weight` from the array and multiplies the values accordingly like `value * weight`. **It has to be noted that a User can change this value by changing the manipulating the sliders, which correspond to the specific variable in the array**

I tried the $watch command like this:

```
$scope.$watch('alerts', function(newValue, oldValue){
  $scope.index = oldValue + (newValue.weight * newValue.value);
}, true);
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$scope.$watch` and listen for changes and when ever changes happened you can update the view. you can also try to use `ng-change="update(alert)"` function and pass the value to function.